# Implicit Differentiation of 3 variables

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Find $\frac{dy}{dz}$ when

$$(-5x+z)^4-2x^3y^6+3yz^6+6y^4z=10.$$

I got an answer of

$$\frac{-24y^3(z-3)z^6+2x^36y^5}{4(-5x+z)^3+8yz^5+6y^4}.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for how to properly render math here.

Comment: Are you assuming $x$ is a function of $z$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You are considering the equation:
\begin{equation*} (-5x+z)^{4}-2x^{3}y^{6}+3yz^{6}+6y^{4}z=10\end{equation*}
and you wish to calculate $\frac{dy}{dz}$. It follows that
\begin{align*} 0&=\frac{d}{dz}{10}=\frac{d}{dz}\left[(-5x+z)^{4}-2x^{3}y^{6}+3yz^{6}+6y^{4}z\right] \\ &=4(z-5x)^{3}\left(1-5\frac{dx}{dz}\right)-2\left[6x^{3}y^{5}\frac{dy}{dz}+3x^{2}\frac{dx}{dz}y^{6}\right]+3\left[6yz^{5}+z^{6}\frac{dy}{dz}\right]+6\left[y^{4}+4zy^{3}\frac{dy}{dz}\right]\end{align*}
Can you take it from here to verify whether or not your answer is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the *differential* of the entire equation
$$\eqalign{
0 &= 6\,d(y^4z) - 2\,d(x^3y^6) +3\,d(yz^6) + d(z-5x)^4 \\
\\
0 &= 6(y^4dz+4zy^3dy) - 2(3x^2y^6dx+6x^3y^5dy) \\
 &\quad+\; 3(z^6dy+6yz^5dz) + 4(z-5x)^3(dz-5\,dx) \\
}$$
Assuming $x$ is held constant (i.e. $\,dx=0$) allows us to drop some terms
$$\eqalign{
0 &= (6y^4dz+24zy^3dy) - (12x^3y^5dy)+ (3z^6dy+18yz^5dz) + 4(z-5x)^3dz \\
0 &= \Big(24zy^3+3z^6-12x^3y^5\Big)dy + \Big(6y^4+18yz^5+4(z-5x)^3\Big)dz \\
}$$
This can be rearranged into the desired partial derivative
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}
 &= \frac{6y^4+18yz^5+4(z-5x)^3}{12x^3y^5-24zy^3-3z^6} \\
}$$

Comment: As a note, it depends on whether the OP is trying to find $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$ or $\frac{dy}{dz}$.  If it is truly $\frac{dy}{dz}$, then you shouldn't drop the $dx$ terms, but you will wind up with other derivatives in your answer.  Unfortunately, most books are not clear on this point.

Comment: @johnnyb That's true. I typically calculate $a\,dx = b\;dy + c\,dz\;$ and then decide whether I need a total or partial derivative. In most applied problems, it's the latter. In this problem, it's unclear.